# Maven is looking in the wrong directory for the Android tools - how can I correct this?

Tags: android, maven-2, maven

I've been following the instructions here - I want to build the helloworld.apk, and generally get started with Android/Maven development.

https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes/wiki

Any time I try to compile I get the following error message:

```
Embedded error: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /home/sal/workspace/foo5 && /home/sal/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-8/tools/aapt/package -m -J /home/sal/workspace/foo5/target/generated-sources/r -M /home/sal/workspace/foo5/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/sal/workspace/foo5/target/generated-sources/combined-resources/res -I /home/sal/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-8/android.jar, Result = 127
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's looking for the aapt utility in an obsolete location. I seem to remember that older versions of the Android SDK had a tools directory for each platform available. This was changed so that there's a sharared tools and platform-tools folder.

How do I make maven use the correct folders.

One solution is simply to copy all the tools into one messy folder, but surely there's a more elegant way of doing this?

Update 0: I already have the SDK path set...

```
<properties>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <!-- Path to the sdk in the file system -->
    <sdkPath>/home/sal/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86</sdkPath>
</properties>
```

Comment: The way you set that those properties is wrong and will not be picked up by the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. Then you do not need to set anything in the pom.xml file

If you insist on using the pom you have to set the sdk.path variable in the configuration element of the maven android pluginn and not as a general property.

And if you still have trouble ask on the maven android developer mailing list.

The other thing you should check is that you use a latest version of the plugin.

Comment: Am I using an old version of the plugin? From what I can tell I'm using the latest version of the archetype. I'm pretty new to MVN tho.

Comment: just set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it generates configutation for maven-android-plugin, try to set:

```
<properties><sdk.path>...</sdk.path></properties>
```

Comment: Actually I already have that set, or at least I think I have something similar set - can you look at the update I added to the original post? The problemm is that it's looking in platforms/android-8/tools when it ought to be looking in platform-tools. The issue is that the structure of the SDK folders have changed.

Comment: I've not seen sdkPath element in examples, what about <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> ? 

Try to run mvn -X compile and look for the plugin settings.